# How to delete for each group and for one variable values after 1 step and create histograms in R

Tags: r

I have dataset (part for example)

```
ndvi=structure(list(district_id = c(72L, 58L, 72L, 58L, 72L, 58L, 
58L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 58L, 72L, 58L, 72L, 58L, 72L, 
58L, 72L), gfid = c(73099L, 59055L, 73104L, 59067L, 73008L, 59006L, 
59111L, 72315L, 72263L, 73174L, 72315L, 72263L, 73104L, 59012L, 
73099L, 59058L, 73099L, 59060L, 73104L, 59127L, 72315L), lon = c("75.98381", 
"76.6595", "76.029083", "76.662102", "76.016747", "76.691063", 
"76.690277", "76.264481", "76.263268", "75.990143", "76.264481", 
"76.263268", "76.029083", "76.636169", "75.98381", "76.692299", 
"75.98381", "76.699669", "76.029083", "76.628418", "76.264481"
), lat = c("23.019079", "28.881411", "22.873091", "29.01403", 
"23.15546", "28.88661", "28.88784", "23.218969", "23.14661", 
"22.99415", "23.218969", "23.14661", "22.873091", "29.00535", 
"23.019079", "28.88608", "23.019079", "28.879801", "22.873091", 
"28.99098", "23.218969"), date = c("08.02.2021", "05.03.2021", 
"08.02.2021", "10.03.2021", "03.02.2021", "05.03.2021", "05.03.2021", 
"08.02.2021", "08.02.2021", "19.01.2021", "23.02.2021", "23.02.2021", 
"13.02.2021", "10.03.2021", "29.01.2021", "05.03.2021", "23.02.2021", 
"05.03.2021", "23.02.2021", "10.03.2021", "13.02.2021"), red = c(32L, 
40L, 44L, 58L, 32L, 70L, 66L, 76L, 68L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 84L, 
108L, 94L, 90L, 100L, 86L, 108L, 94L), green = c(184L, 216L, 
148L, 202L, 104L, 350L, 234L, 260L, 220L, 276L, 220L, 220L, 188L, 
196L, 340L, 310L, 226L, 436L, 166L, 316L, 246L), blue = c(1L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 78L, 26L, 60L, 52L, 28L, 44L, 76L, 44L, 1L, 92L, 
70L, 82L, 100L, 46L, 12L, 38L), nir = c(4872L, 4008L, 4328L, 
4424L, 2332L, 4856L, 4216L, 4696L, 4200L, 4328L, 4248L, 4040L, 
3816L, 4072L, 5176L, 4456L, 4232L, 4680L, 4008L, 5000L, 4344L
), swir = c(1120L, 1184L, 1056L, 1376L, 592L, 1584L, 1200L, 1120L, 
1072L, 1136L, 928L, 992L, 1056L, 1440L, 1248L, 1296L, 1040L, 
1760L, 928L, 1696L, 1072L), B05 = c(352L, 416L, 288L, 544L, 272L, 
672L, 480L, 480L, 416L, 464L, 352L, 416L, 336L, 560L, 544L, 480L, 
416L, 928L, 288L, 672L, 416L), B06 = c(2912L, 2528L, 2592L, 3040L, 
1488L, 3296L, 2720L, 3104L, 2672L, 2976L, 2464L, 2352L, 2272L, 
3088L, 3296L, 2912L, 2416L, 3168L, 2208L, 3568L, 2720L), B07 = c(4640L, 
3872L, 4192L, 4448L, 2128L, 4768L, 4000L, 4640L, 3984L, 4336L, 
4064L, 3872L, 3808L, 4448L, 4768L, 4256L, 3920L, 3936L, 3808L, 
4960L, 4384L), B08A = c(4752L, 3936L, 4384L, 4576L, 2192L, 4832L, 
4064L, 4704L, 4128L, 4400L, 4320L, 4064L, 4000L, 4448L, 4960L, 
4256L, 4192L, 4176L, 4064L, 5024L, 4512L), B12 = c(464L, 544L, 
416L, 608L, 240L, 736L, 544L, 496L, 480L, 464L, 416L, 480L, 480L, 
672L, 528L, 608L, 416L, 928L, 416L, 800L, 480L), ndvi = c(0.986949429, 
0.980237154, 0.979871912, 0.974118697, 0.972927241, 0.971579374, 
0.969173283, 0.968147527, 0.968134957, 0.965485921, 0.964847363, 
0.963070942, 0.960945529, 0.959576515, 0.959121877, 0.958681318, 
0.958352614, 0.958158995, 0.957987298, 0.95771339, 0.957638575
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

How for any value of ndvi if it is more than 0.8  delete values in one step?
I will clarify the question. We take the district = 72,
for example, the first line ndvi > 0.8 and = 0.98, then the next value must be deleted, that is, we delete 0.97987191. We do not touch the following value, but we also delete 4.
That is, the removal goes through 1 step.
Values Remain
1-3-5,but
2-4 are removed in order and so on until the end for each district(group variable) separately.
Well, the output will be something like this

```
  district_id  gfid       lon       lat       date red green blue  nir swir B05  B06  B07 B08A B12
1          72 73099  75.98381 23.019079 08.02.2021  32   184    1 4872 1120 352 2912 4640 4752 464
2          72 73104 76.029083 22.873091 08.02.2021  44   148    1 4328 1056 288 2592 4192 4384 416
3          72 73008 76.016747  23.15546 03.02.2021  32   104    1 2332  592 272 1488 2128 2192 240
4          72 72315 76.264481 23.218969 08.02.2021  76   260   60 4696 1120 480 3104 4640 4704 496
5          72 72263 76.263268  23.14661 08.02.2021  68   220   52 4200 1072 416 2672 3984 4128 480
6          72 73174 75.990143  22.99415 19.01.2021  76   276   28 4328 1136 464 2976 4336 4400 464
       ndvi
1 0.9869494
2        NA
3 0.9729272
4        NA
5 0.9681350
6        NA
```

After we got the desired output, we need to replace the resulting gaps with the average value between 2 points. Average  value of 1 and 3 points, is inserted into the second point, and so on.
Average  value of 3 and 5 points is inserted into 4 point.

And lastly, I need for each `district_id` the ndvi histogram before we deleted the values and after we restored the deleted ones.

What is the easiest way to remove the ndvi value after 1 step and then restore the average for each district separately, and also get histograms before and after the removal of values for each district.

Thanks for any of your help.

Comment: `for each district_id the ndvi histogram before we deleted the values and after we restored the deleted ones` ... do your histogram before any answer you receive ... and then after it. Why do you need that in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a combination of a reduction (e.g., `base::Reduce` or `purrr::reduce`) and a "coalesce" (or sliding-window average). I say "reduce" because since *all* of your data are over 0.8 but you don't want neighboring values (in the same `district_id` to both be converted to `NA`), we need to consider whether we nulled the previous value before considering nulling this value.

I'll demo using `dplyr`, as it makes the grouping and operations a little simpler to visualize. This can be translated to base R (or just as easily `data.table`).

Up front, the whole solution, replacing `ndvi` in-place:

```r
library(dplyr)
ndvi %>%
  group_by(district_id) %>%
  mutate(
    ndvi = Reduce(function(prev, this) if (is.na(prev) | prev <= 0.8) this else this[NA],
                  ndvi, accumulate = TRUE),
    ndvi = coalesce(ndvi, (lag(ndvi) + lead(ndvi))/2)
  )
```

A walk-through for each step:

```r
library(dplyr)
ndvi %>%
  group_by(district_id) %>%
  mutate(ndvi2 = Reduce(function(prev, this) if (is.na(prev) | prev <= 0.8) this else this[NA], ndvi, accumulate = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(district_id == 72)
# # A tibble: 13 × 17
# # Groups:   district_id [1]
#    district_id  gfid lon       lat    date    red green  blue   nir  swir   B05   B06   B07  B08A   B12  ndvi  ndvi2
#          <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1          72 73099 75.98381  23.01… 08.0…    32   184     1  4872  1120   352  2912  4640  4752   464 0.987  0.987
#  2          72 73104 76.029083 22.87… 08.0…    44   148     1  4328  1056   288  2592  4192  4384   416 0.980 NA    
#  3          72 73008 76.016747 23.15… 03.0…    32   104     1  2332   592   272  1488  2128  2192   240 0.973  0.973
#  4          72 72315 76.264481 23.21… 08.0…    76   260    60  4696  1120   480  3104  4640  4704   496 0.968 NA    
#  5          72 72263 76.263268 23.14… 08.0…    68   220    52  4200  1072   416  2672  3984  4128   480 0.968  0.968
#  6          72 73174 75.990143 22.99… 19.0…    76   276    28  4328  1136   464  2976  4336  4400   464 0.965 NA    
#  7          72 72315 76.264481 23.21… 23.0…    76   220    44  4248   928   352  2464  4064  4320   416 0.965  0.965
#  8          72 72263 76.263268 23.14… 23.0…    76   220    76  4040   992   416  2352  3872  4064   480 0.963 NA    
#  9          72 73104 76.029083 22.87… 13.0…    76   188    44  3816  1056   336  2272  3808  4000   480 0.961  0.961
# 10          72 73099 75.98381  23.01… 29.0…   108   340    92  5176  1248   544  3296  4768  4960   528 0.959 NA    
# 11          72 73099 75.98381  23.01… 23.0…    90   226    82  4232  1040   416  2416  3920  4192   416 0.958  0.958
# 12          72 73104 76.029083 22.87… 23.0…    86   166    46  4008   928   288  2208  3808  4064   416 0.958 NA    
# 13          72 72315 76.264481 23.21… 13.0…    94   246    38  4344  1072   416  2720  4384  4512   480 0.958  0.958
```

That verifies that we are nulling every other (since all are over 0.8) value in `ndvi2`.

For the averaging, we can do a simple `(lag()+lead())/2` averaging as long as you are certain that no other `NA` values exist. (If it does naturally exist, you might move to `zoo::rollmean` or similar for a true sliding window mean, assisted with `if_else`.)

```r
ndvi %>%
  group_by(district_id) %>%
  mutate(ndvi2 = Reduce(function(prev, this) if (is.na(prev) | prev <= 0.8) this else this[NA], ndvi, accumulate = TRUE), ndvi3 = coalesce(ndvi2, (lag(ndvi2) + lead(ndvi2))/2)) %>%
  filter(district_id == 72)
# # A tibble: 13 × 18
# # Groups:   district_id [1]
#    district…¹  gfid lon   lat   date    red green  blue   nir  swir   B05   B06   B07  B08A   B12  ndvi  ndvi2 ndvi3
#         <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1         72 73099 75.9… 23.0… 08.0…    32   184     1  4872  1120   352  2912  4640  4752   464 0.987  0.987 0.987
#  2         72 73104 76.0… 22.8… 08.0…    44   148     1  4328  1056   288  2592  4192  4384   416 0.980 NA     0.980
#  3         72 73008 76.0… 23.1… 03.0…    32   104     1  2332   592   272  1488  2128  2192   240 0.973  0.973 0.973
#  4         72 72315 76.2… 23.2… 08.0…    76   260    60  4696  1120   480  3104  4640  4704   496 0.968 NA     0.971
#  5         72 72263 76.2… 23.1… 08.0…    68   220    52  4200  1072   416  2672  3984  4128   480 0.968  0.968 0.968
#  6         72 73174 75.9… 22.9… 19.0…    76   276    28  4328  1136   464  2976  4336  4400   464 0.965 NA     0.966
#  7         72 72315 76.2… 23.2… 23.0…    76   220    44  4248   928   352  2464  4064  4320   416 0.965  0.965 0.965
#  8         72 72263 76.2… 23.1… 23.0…    76   220    76  4040   992   416  2352  3872  4064   480 0.963 NA     0.963
#  9         72 73104 76.0… 22.8… 13.0…    76   188    44  3816  1056   336  2272  3808  4000   480 0.961  0.961 0.961
# 10         72 73099 75.9… 23.0… 29.0…   108   340    92  5176  1248   544  3296  4768  4960   528 0.959 NA     0.960
# 11         72 73099 75.9… 23.0… 23.0…    90   226    82  4232  1040   416  2416  3920  4192   416 0.958  0.958 0.958
# 12         72 73104 76.0… 22.8… 23.0…    86   166    46  4008   928   288  2208  3808  4064   416 0.958 NA     0.958
# 13         72 72315 76.2… 23.2… 13.0…    94   246    38  4344  1072   416  2720  4384  4512   480 0.958  0.958 0.958
# # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​district_id
```